# Regex to get the inner content from xml element

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get the value **Status.** from this piece of xml:

```
string xml = "<value z:Id=\"8\" z:Type=\"System.String\" z:Assembly=\"0\">Status.</value>";

Regex regexFieldValue = new Regex("z:Assembly=\"0\">(?<fieldValue>[^<|\\.|.]+)</value>");

Match match = regexFieldValue.Match(xml);
if (match.Success)
{
    Group group = match.Groups["fieldValue"];
    return group.Value;
}
```

Tanks

Comment: Your regex would be `"z:Assembly=\"0\">(?<fieldValue>[^<>]+)</value>"`

Comment: The usual advice is "Use a parser" because XML isn't a regular language.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Yeah, but XML parsers are so boring and easy to use. It's much cooler to write some incomprehensible regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^<|\\.|.]+` won't do as you expected. So change this to `[^<>]+` in your regex.

```
z:Assembly=\"0\">(?<fieldValue>[^<>]+)</value>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pD3xY6/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
z:Assembly=\\"0\\">(?<fieldValue>(?:(?!<\/value>).)*)<\/value>
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/60